# Sum entries belonging to the same date

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have two columns in a table. `Column1` contains DateTime entries whereas Column2 contains nutrient entries. There are multiple nutrient entries which belong to the same date like:

[image]

How can I get the sum of the nutrient values for each day?

For instance, for 4/17/2017 I wanted a value of 9 and for 4/18/2017 it should be 3.

Answer (score 5):

check this.

```
 SELECT DATE, SUM(Nutrient) AS NutrientSum
FROM Table 
GROUP BY DATE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
SELECT      DateColumn,
            SUM(Nutrient) AS NutrientSum
FROM        Tab 
GROUP BY    DateColumn
```

You can see this here -> http://rextester.com/QGET49240

Answer (score 0):

If the dates can have different time components then:

```
SELECT TRUNC( "Date" ) AS "Date",
       SUM( Nutrient ) AS TotalNutrients
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY TRUNC( "Date" )
```

If they are always the same time component (i.e. `00:00`) then:

```
SELECT "Date",
       SUM( Nutrient ) AS TotalNutrients
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY "Date"
```